# How to add digital signature image to pdf in ios?

Tags: iphone, pdf, digital-signature, digital-certificate

Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

I am working on iphone development. This is new for me.

I need to generate a pdf with digital signature. I don't have any idea about this . I have googled past 1 week, still i am not able to crack this problem.

Please can anybody explain the step by step procedure or provide me some source code example.
Also provide me some good links.

Comment: Do you want to create the PDF programmatically? If so you'll need to start reading up on Core Text. It's a pretty advanced framework but has nearly unlimited potential.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Comment: another great PDF creation tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: One more for iOS Certificate, Key, and Trust Services though its a C API:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawSign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this may be help you :[Convert an image to pdf](http://ipdfdev.com/2011/04/22/convert-an-image-to-pdf-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/#more-158)

Answer (score -1):

Please have a  look at this.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/17/sign-pdf-with-digital-signature-mac-os-x/
 ----or------
  http://layersmagazine.com/digital-signatures-acrobat8.html

hope this may Help you

Comment: I guess the user is finding answer for iOS..!!

Comment: @sachi : sorry dear but i am not able to find any..!